# AppVeyor GitHub: : Invalid argument fatal: unable to checkout working tree

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, appveyor

I am using AppVeyor for my GitHub Project.
Since some time, the built always fails.

I keep getting this message.

> git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS.git C:\projects\imputets
>   : Invalid argument
>   fatal: unable to checkout working tree
>   warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
>   You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
>   and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
>   Command exited with code 128

I am assuming, it is no problem with the code...rather a error checking out the files from github. I am wondering now how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this error is not specific to AppVeyor environment - it can be reproduced locally on my dev machine. Look at the screenshot below. I tried to do `git checkout -f HEAD` as suggested in the error message but no avail. Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank! This helped me solve my problem. Just had to delete the Icon file (which was an artifact)